# ORA-00936: missing expression - Line 62

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been trying to identify what's wrong with the Insert Statement in the Execute Immediate for few hours without luck. Made sure that I am not missing any commas or entering any incorrect character.

I have gone through all the answers on SO and other websites trying to figure out what could I be doing wrong but no luck.

Running this function results in the following error (error line starts with "-->" Please ignore it as its just for highlighting purpose):

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06512: at "BDW_AMPS.COUNT_RECORDS", line 62
```

and here's the PL/SQL Code for the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_records (
    p_test_case_id   IN NUMBER,
    p_table_name     IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

    v_amt_recs            INT;
    v_test_result         VARCHAR2(10);
    v_threshold_val       VARCHAR2(10);
    v_test_suite_table    VARCHAR2(100);
    v_test_result_id      NUMBER;
    v_batch_id            NUMBER;
    v_report_id           NUMBER;
    v_test_seq_no         NUMBER;
    v_session_name        VARCHAR2(100);
    v_error_description   VARCHAR2(100);
    v_process_by          VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    v_test_suite_table := 'bdw_amps.spares_bdw_test_suite';
    v_process_by := 'INFORMATICA';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT THRESHHOLD_VALUE FROM '
                      || v_test_suite_table
                      || ' WHERE TEST_CASE_ID = '
                      || p_test_case_id
    INTO v_threshold_val;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || p_table_name
    INTO v_amt_recs;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT BDW_AMPS.SPARES_TEST_SEQ_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL'
    INTO v_test_result_id;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT MAX(BATCH_ID) FROM BDW_AMPS.spares_bdw_session_audit 
     WHERE SESSION_NAME=(SELECT SESSION_NAME FROM '
                      || v_test_suite_table
                      || ' WHERE TEST_CASE_ID = '
                      || p_test_case_id
                      || ')'
    INTO v_batch_id;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT REPORT_ID FROM '
                      || v_test_suite_table
                      || ' WHERE TEST_CASE_ID = '
                      || p_test_case_id
    INTO v_report_id;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT TEST_SEQ FROM '
                      || v_test_suite_table
                      || ' WHERE TEST_CASE_ID = '
                      || p_test_case_id
    INTO v_test_seq_no;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT SESSION_NAME FROM '
                      || v_test_suite_table
                      || ' WHERE TEST_CASE_ID = '
                      || p_test_case_id
    INTO v_session_name;

    IF
        v_amt_recs > v_threshold_val
    THEN
        v_test_result := 'PASS';

    --> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO BDW_AMPS.spares_bdw_test_results(
        TEST_RESULT_ID, 
        BATCH_ID, 
        REPORT_ID, 
        TEST_CASE_ID, 
        TEST_SEQ_NO, 
        TABLE_NAME, 
        SESSION_NAME, 
        TEST_RESULT, 
        PROCESS_DATE, 
        PROCESS_BY
        )
        VALUES 
        ('|| v_test_result_id || ',
        ' || v_batch_id || ',
        ' || v_report_id || ',
        ' || p_test_case_id || ',
        ' || v_test_seq_no || ',
        ' || p_table_name || ',
        ' || v_session_name || ',
        ' || v_test_result || ',
        SYSDATE,
        ' || v_process_by || '
        )';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'commit';

    ELSE
        v_test_result := 'FAIL';
        v_error_description := 'Count: ' || v_amt_recs || ' is greater than threshold value: ' || v_threshold_val;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO BDW_AMPS.spares_bdw_test_results(
    TEST_RESULT_ID, 
    BATCH_ID, 
    REPORT_ID, 
    TEST_CASE_ID, 
    TEST_SEQ_NO, 
    TABLE_NAME, 
    SESSION_NAME, 
    TEST_RESULT,
    ERROR_DESCRIPTION,
    PROCESS_DATE, 
    PROCESS_BY
    )
    VALUES (
    '|| v_test_result_id || ',
    ' || v_batch_id || ',
    ' || v_report_id || ',
    ' || p_test_case_id || ',
    ' || v_test_seq_no || ',
    ' || p_table_name  || ',
    ' || v_session_name || ',
    ' || v_test_result || ',
    ' || v_error_description || ',
    SYSDATE,
    ' || v_process_by  || '
    )';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'commit';

    END IF;

    RETURN v_test_result;
END;
```

Comment: highlighted the errorenous line number with "-->"

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help are off topic

Comment: just replace `SYSDATE,` with `' || SYSDATE || ',`

Comment: hi @BarbarosÖzhan thanks for replying but that didn't help. same error.

Comment: hi Gautham you're welcome replace `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'commit';` with `commit;` also

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan good idea but not sure how it helps in identifying the issue.

Comment: excuse me, get rid of all `execute  immediate` starting from your highlighted line(61). You don't need

Comment: String values in the `values` clause need to be quoted, so you will need to concatenate some extra quote characters for those. Have the code print out the generated statement and the issue should be pretty clear. (Though Barbaros has a good point that dynamic SQL appears to be unnecessary here.)

Comment: thank you @WilliamRobertson and Barbaros 
I updated the code in the post with your recommendations and its working as intended now. I'm curious to why it wasn't working before. 
Thanks for your recommendations btw.

Comment: Is `bdw_amps.spares_bdw_test_suite` fix table name? In this case you don't need even the dynamic select statements.

Comment: Now that you've edited the code shown in the question we don't know where the error occurs or what the error is. Please edit your question and provide the current information. Thanks.

Comment: @Wernfried - it wont be static. i did that for the sake of this example.

Comment: @Asadefa - "Questions seeking debugging help are off topic" - this is not correct. [From the relevant help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"

Comment: Apologies for the edits@BobJarvis. I have rolled back the code to its original state

Comment: @BobJarvis Well, I flagged it and the flag got marked as helpful. So there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DML(`INSERT`) statements do not need EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statements. So, remove them after line 61 :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_records (
    p_test_case_id   IN NUMBER,
    p_table_name     IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

    v_amt_recs            INT;
    v_test_result         VARCHAR2(10);
    v_threshold_val       VARCHAR2(10);
    v_test_suite_table    VARCHAR2(100);
    v_test_result_id      NUMBER;
    v_batch_id            NUMBER;
    v_report_id           NUMBER;
    v_test_seq_no         NUMBER;
    v_session_name        VARCHAR2(100);
    v_error_description   VARCHAR2(100);
    v_process_by          VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    v_test_suite_table := 'bdw_amps.spares_bdw_test_suite';
    v_process_by := 'INFORMATICA';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || p_table_name
    INTO v_amt_recs;

    v_test_result_id := BDW_AMPS.SPARES_TEST_SEQ_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT MAX(BATCH_ID) FROM BDW_AMPS.spares_bdw_session_audit 
     WHERE SESSION_NAME=(SELECT SESSION_NAME FROM '
                  || v_test_suite_table
                      || ' WHERE TEST_CASE_ID = '
                      || p_test_case_id
                      || ')'
    INTO v_batch_id;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT THRESHHOLD_VALUE, REPORT_ID, TEST_SEQ,SESSION_NAME FROM '
                      || v_test_suite_table
                      || ' WHERE TEST_CASE_ID = :caseId'
    INTO v_threshold_val,v_report_id,v_test_seq_no,v_session_name
    USING p_test_case_id;

    IF
        v_amt_recs > v_threshold_val
    THEN
        v_test_result := 'PASS';

    INSERT INTO BDW_AMPS.spares_bdw_test_results(
        TEST_RESULT_ID, 
        BATCH_ID, 
        REPORT_ID, 
        TEST_CASE_ID, 
        TEST_SEQ_NO, 
        TABLE_NAME, 
        SESSION_NAME, 
        TEST_RESULT, 
        PROCESS_DATE, 
        PROCESS_BY
        )
        VALUES 
        ( v_test_result_id ,
          v_batch_id ,
          v_report_id ,
          p_test_case_id ,
          v_test_seq_no ,
          p_table_name ,
          v_session_name ,
          v_test_result ,
          SYSDATE,
         v_process_by 
        );

    commit;

    ELSE
        v_test_result := 'FAIL';
        v_error_description := 'Count: ' || v_amt_recs || ' is greater than threshold value: ' || v_threshold_val;

    INSERT INTO BDW_AMPS.spares_bdw_test_results(
    TEST_RESULT_ID, 
    BATCH_ID, 
    REPORT_ID, 
    TEST_CASE_ID, 
    TEST_SEQ_NO, 
    TABLE_NAME, 
    SESSION_NAME, 
    TEST_RESULT,
    ERROR_DESCRIPTION,
    PROCESS_DATE, 
    PROCESS_BY
    )
    VALUES (
    v_test_result_id ,
     v_batch_id ,
     v_report_id ,
     p_test_case_id ,
     v_test_seq_no ,
     p_table_name  ,
     v_session_name ,
     v_test_result ,
     v_error_description ,
    SYSDATE,
     v_process_by  
    );
    commit;

    END IF;

    RETURN v_test_result;
END;
```

while usage of them are right for `SELECT` statements because of dynamic table names.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is a simplified example of something that really does need to be dynamic, one issue is that the string values are not quoted. (If you'd had date values they would need special handling too.)

For example:

```
create table demo (numcol number, stringcol varchar2(20));

declare
    l_num number := 123;
    l_string varchar2(20) := 'Kittens';
    l_sql long := 'insert into demo(numcol, stringcol) values ('||l_num||', '||l_string||')';
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
    execute immediate l_sql;
end;
/
```

Generated code:

```
insert into demo(numcol, stringcol) values (123, Kittens)
```

Fails with:

```
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

The error will vary depending on the contents of the string. For example, if it contains spaces:

```
declare
    l_num number := 123;
    l_string varchar2(20) := 'Kittens are cute';
    l_sql long := 'insert into demo(numcol, stringcol) values ('||l_num||', '||l_string||')';
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
    execute immediate l_sql;
end;
/
```

Generated code:

```
insert into demo(numcol, stringcol) values (123, Kittens are cute)

ORA-00917: missing comma
```

or commas:

```
declare
    l_num number := 123;
    l_string varchar2(20) := 'Kittens, Puppies';
    l_sql long := 'insert into demo(numcol, stringcol) values ('||l_num||', '||l_string||')';
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
    execute immediate l_sql;
end;
/

insert into demo(numcol, stringcol) values (123, Kittens, Puppies)

ORA-00913: too many values
```

You need to build the quoting:

```
declare
    l_num number := 123;
    l_string varchar2(20) := 'Kittens, Puppies';
    l_sql long := 'insert into demo(numcol, stringcol) values ('||l_num||', '''||l_string||''')';
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
    execute immediate l_sql;
end;
/
```

so that you generate

```
insert into demo(numcol, stringcol) values (123, 'Kittens, Puppies')
```

(If the string could contain quote characters, that would need more work.)

It's worth always building the dynamic SQL as a variable and printing or logging it on failure, as it's usually pretty clear what the issue is when you can see the code.

Another point is that concatenating values like this is resource-intensive, as Oracle tries to cache SQL statements for reuse, so they will be individually parsed and optimised and take space in the cache, but they will never be reused. If this is going to be frequently run with different values, you should consider using bind variables via the [`using` clause of `execute immediate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73).

Comment: Thank you Will for the explanation. I had realized that about strings bit later when I started looking at my code past the point of failure (line 62).

Comment: The comment about printing out your Dynamic SQL statements is really a good tip!! Thanks again :)